# Lubuntu Logout Button Doesn't Work

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, shutdown, logout

I just installed the Lubuntu Desktop on top of my Ubuntu 14.04 install.

I can login in to any Desktop Environment from the start-up fine but once I'm in Lubuntu my Menu << Logout button does nothing. Also, on the bottom right, my Shutdown ethernet, keyboard, and volume settings are grayed out and I am unable to select them. Only way to shutdown or reboot is from command line.

Do I need to fix my install?

Comment: Which metapackage did you actually install? Do you remember? `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` installs different things than `sudo apt-get install lxde`, and the lxde metapackage is less closely maintained in ubuntu than lubuntu-desktop - there are reported dependency issue bugs with the Ubuntu lxde metapackage.

Comment: If you go to menu prefrences default apps for lxsession what is set for quit manager. Also do you have lxsession-logout isntalled that should let you quit.

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies and sorry about not responding right away. To answer your queries, yes lxsession is installed and after checking my command history I did indeed install lubuntu-desktop. What I have discovered since my initial post is that I can get the buttons to respond but only on a double click, which is not terribly intuitive or desired. So any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On Panel at extreme right if you find Shutdown, triple click on Shutdown as fast as you can, then lubuntu will ask you what to do
if you dont have a shutdown option ... then use a dock like DOCKY or CAIRO